# Computations between dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have done something similar in SQL and it's fairly trivial but I don't know how to do this in Python. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Student   Class       Result      Exam
a         First       Bad         t1
a         First       Bad         t2
a         First       Good        t2
b         Second      Bad         t1
c         First       Good        t3
c         First       Bad         t2
d         Third       Bad         t1
d         Third       Bad         t4
d         Third       Good        t4
e         Fourth      Good        t3
e         Fourth      Good        t2
f         Third       Good        t1
g         Fourth      Good        t4
g         Fourth      Bad         t3
```

A student can only be in one class. A student can take an exam multiple times, and get a different score (the order is not chronological so I don't really care about what exam they are taking). **The goal is to find out whether some Classes perform better than others.**

For that, my idea was to turn the number of good and bad answers from each student, compute a score like `score = good/(good+bad)`, and then averaging again:

```
Student   Class     Score    ClassScore  
a         First     0.33          0.415   
b         Second       0              0
c         First      0.5          0.415
d         Third     0.33          0.665
e         Fourth       1           0.75
f         Third        1          0.665
g         Fourth     0.5           0.75
```

This looks extremely messy and there is no clear rank of the classes. Is there any possibility of obtaining a score for each team at once, without jumping from dataframe to dataframe, and moreover, a way to display it more clearly?

Comment: with pandas (not with python).  Pandas != python ;)  This is eminently solveable with pandas (and with plain python) and doubtless somebody who *likes* pandas will be along to solve it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

[edit] let's have a reproducible example:

Copy of the raw data to a data.txt file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+')
```

The answer:

```
# first line simplifies the rest of the expression
df['result_bin'] = df['Result'] == 'Good'
df.groupby(['Class', 'Student'])['result_bin'].mean().groupby('Class').mean()
```

This returns:

```
Class
First     0.416667
Fourth    0.750000
Second    0.000000
Third     0.666667
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it on my (huge) dataframe and it returns a bool object, with some of the Classes (not all) and the second column is "Bad" overall.

Comment: I'll edit my answer for reproducibility purposes.

Comment: `read_csv` can use regex as separator so you could use `read_csv(..., sep=" +")` instead of converting `sub(' +', '\t', ...)`. BTW: In example I would use text directly in code `read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep="\s+")`